# Structure of a bijection on $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be odd. $f(x)=2x\mod n$ defines a bijection on $\mathbb{Z}_n$. For example, let's look at the case of $n=15$. If we start at $1$ and keep applying this bijection we get $1\to 2\to 4\to 8\to 1$. Let's call this a cycle. Other cycles generated by $f$ are $3\to 6\to 12\to 9\to 3$, $5\to 10\to 5$, $7\to 14\to 13\to 11\to 7$, $0\to 0$.

> I am trying to find the structure of these cycles for any given odd $n$ for example the number of such cycles for a given odd $n$.

I am just looking for a reference/pointers if it is a known result. I was not able to either find a source or analyze it myself. Thanks.

Comment: These are the orbits of the $\langle2\rangle\subseteq\mathbb Z_n^\times$-action on $\mathbb Z_n$. Maybe start by looking at the order of $2\in\mathbb Z_n^\times$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the special case where $n$ is prime, so we'll call it $p$ instead of $n$. Then look at the numbers $2^r-1$, $r=1,2,\dots$, until you find one divisible by $p$ [exercise: there is always such a number]. Let that one be $2^d-1$. Then we call $d$ the *order* of $2$, modulo $p$. Then every cycle is a $d$-cycle, and $d$ is a divisor of $p-1$. In some cases, $d=p-1$; in such cases, we say $2$ is a *primitive root* modulo $p$. It is believed, but not proved, that there are infinitely many such $p$.

If $n$ is not prime, things are more complicated, but it amounts to looking at the situation for each of the prime power factors of $n$.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Can we say anything more than $d$ is a divisor of $p-1$ given a $p$?

Comment: Not much. Well, for any given $p$, it's a finite calculation to find $d$, albeit by brute force. And you know it's a divisor of $p-1$, so that cuts down the possibilities. And if $p\equiv\pm1\bmod8$ then $d$ is a divisor of $(p-1)/2$. But no simple formula is known.